# How to enable word confidence using gcloud command line

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to enable the word level confidence for the Speech API using the gcloud command.  However, the enable_word_confidence parameter seems to be available in beta version only.  Is there a way to configure the parameter using the gcloud command or edit the configuration file? 
Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer … the correct command should be 
   gcloud alpha ml speech recognize filename --language-code=en --include-word-confidence

since the option is only available in the alpha version only.